# Create Roles and Users in magento but as a non admin

Tags: magento, permissions, roles

My client wants the access to create `users and roles in magento`, i have already given him a limited users created by myself, in that `users` there is not permission to add `users and roles`.

My question: Is there any way i can give him permissions to add users and roles but, all `the menus that i have made hidden should stay hidden`.

**What i Want to achieve**

I want to give access of creating roles and users to my client, but i don't to revel some menu like "System" to him

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.X:
System->Permission->Roles->(Role Name)->Roles Resources->Custom

In Magneto 2.X:
System->User Roles->(Role Name)->Roles Resources->Custom

Comment: I am able to find that already.
What i am look for there is that, i want to give access of creating roles and users to my client, but i don't to revel some menu like "Configuration" under "system" to him.

Comment: How about enable System->Permission->Roles after my steps?

Answer (score 0):

To give the access for "Roles and User" you have to reveal the
"system" menu to the user as it's the parent of "Roles and User". But, you can disable other inner menus by unchecking them.

You have to only check the System > Permission > Roles > User Bosex from Roles Resouce Tree and it will only allow the user to access the Roles and User.